# Would sharding Monero work with tahoe-LAFS as storage?

Tags: scalability

Would sharding Monero work with tahoe-LAFS with dynamically sizing container on local storage, specifically when integration with I2P using Kovri is finalized, to bring I2P tahoe-LAFS distributed storage?

Another idea would be to have a number of decentralized nodes announcing themselves to the network that have the entire updated blockchain un-sharded in tahoe-LAFS to be synced with the sharded tahoe-LAFS blockchain.

See also:
http://www.lothar.com/blog/55-Git-over-Tahoe-LAFS/